# Compare list of files using beyond compare

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare3, beyondcompare4

I'm trying to compare subset of files between two folders using beyond compare.

example:
folder A , and folder B.
I want to compare specific files from the directories :

c/d/foo.java

e/f/bar.java

filter won't help here since I want to choose files by name, not by file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare's filename filters can include path information or complete filenames; they're not limited to just extensions.  From the [File Masks](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/sessiondirnamefilter.html) topic in the help:

> Relative file masks affect files or folders in specific locations.
>   `p\f`       f must be in folder p.
>   `.\f`       f must be in the base folder.
>   `...\f`     f may have zero or more parent folders.
>
> Examples:
>   `Windows\*.txt` affects any text file in any included folder named Windows.
>   `...\Windows\*.txt` affects any text file in any folder named Windows.
>   `.\Windows\*.txt` affects any text file in a folder named Windows that is in the base folder.

For your specific example, you can use `c/d/foo.java` just like you wrote it.